# Is there any free g729 or g711 converter?

Tags: mp3, wav, converters, wma

I need converter to convert G729 or G711 files to wav,wma,mp3 or any other format witch can play for example Windows Media Player.

Comment: If this is programming related please provide the context. Otherwise this sounds like a question for superuser.com.

Comment: Thanks for link,but I need to use converter programmatically.It must spot command line arguments for files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy Noro. Try [this](http://www.archived-mails.info/wav2g729-freeware-to-convert-between-wav-and-g729-t2095.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can decode using va_g729_decoder.exe to pcm file.then convert that to wav using sox.